# Is "Understanding of Each Other" correct?

Tags: pronouns, british-english, stative-verbs

The word "understanding" is a noun and also an adjective. The verb "understand" is non-dynamic. "Each other" is a pronoun that deals with reciprocal action.

In standard British English, can this motto be  grammatically correct?

> **Understanding of Each Other**.

Users of standard American English may also post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

> **Understanding of Each Other**

Is **grammatically correct** and is a **gerund phrase**, it is not a complete sentence and as a **motto** does not need to be.

Better phrasing might be

> **The Understanding of Each Other**
>   **To Understand Each Other**
>
> **Understand Each Other**
>   *intellegere inter se*

depending if the motto originates in English or is a translation from somewhere else

Comment: Peter, I think that translations should respect the rules of usage of the target language.  What about 'To understand each other/one another?'.  As a gerund phrase, think about "LOOKING OF EACH OTHER".   lol!

Answer (score 1):

It is grammatical; but to me, it reads oddly as a motto. I think this is because the "of" forces interpretation of "understanding" as a verbal noun so the whole phrase is a noun phrase.

"Understanding one another" would be read as a verb phrase with a participle, and to my ear is more comfortable as a motto.

Comment: Colin, as a verb phrase with a participle, okay if we force a stative verb to be used in the progressive form.  Even if allowed, what is "of each other" doing there?  Because of space, I'd simply say that the use of  "of" is a problem and the use of  " each other" is a problem as well, even as a motto!  Thanks for the insightful response.

Comment: A participle of a stative verb is fine: only when you use it with a part of BE does it become a continuous, and give problems for stative verbs. "Each other" conveys a reciprocity: without it, it might imply "We understand you", which is less than the motto conveys as you have it.